# inserting multiple entry into multiple table php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Following the tutorial [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to save multiple entry in database i came up with this code

```
foreach($array as $value){
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
     $stmt->bindParam(':name', $value['name']);
     $stmt->bindParam(':value', $value['value']);
     $stmt->execute();
}

foreach($array1 as $value){
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO user (firstname, surname) VALUES (:fname, :sname)");
      $stmt -> bindParam(':fname', 'John');
      $stmt -> bindParam(':sname', 'Smith');
      $stmt -> execute();
}
```

I have something like this just different table and value but the code is the same. I  want to ask why the second `foreach` didnt fire,it was not saved only the first `foreach` got fired and only the first set of data was saved.How to make it that they both get fired and saved.

Comment: have you tried printing the `$array1`? does it have values or not, use `print_r($array1)`

Comment: no... you can't use `f-name` and `s-name`, try replacing it with `f_name` and `s_name`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the same keywords like you did for the first array
Replace:
    VALUES (:f-name, :s-name)") 
by

```
VALUES (:fname, :sname)")
```

because your stmt call fname and sname, but not s-name and f-name